How to remove string before a certain delimiter in R?
I apologize in advance for the naivety of my question, I did not find a way to do this in R.
I have several character strings that look like this :

sample.names1<-c("S0938-CR1","S0957-AB8","S0971-EGFP1-10")

I would like to remove the characters that appear before the first "-", in order to keep only
CR1, AB8 and EGFP1-10
I tried

sample.names <- sapply(strsplit(basename(sample.names1), "-"), [, 2)

But this did not keep what came after the second "-".
Thank you !

In (1) ^ matches the beginning of string, .* matches everything and ? specifies the shortest match.  - matches itself.
In (2) strcapture extracts everything after the first - producing a data.frame which we then reduce to a vector.
In (3) we show a strsplit solution.
In (4) we replace the first - with a / and then treating that as a file path extract the base name.
In (5) use regexpr to find the position of the first - and then use substring with that position plus 1 to extract the desired portion.
# 1
sub("^.*?-", "", sample.names1)
## [1] "CR1"      "AB8"      "EGFP1-10"

# 2
strcapture("-(.*)", sample.names1, list(""))[[1]]
## [1] "CR1"      "AB8"      "EGFP1-10"

# 3
sapply(strsplit(sample.names1, "-"), \(x) paste(tail(x, -1), collapse = "-"))
## [1] "CR1"      "AB8"      "EGFP1-10"

# 4
basename(sub("-", "/", sample.names1))
## [1] "CR1"      "AB8"      "EGFP1-10"

# 5
substring(sample.names1, regexpr("-", sample.names1) + 1)
## [1] "CR1"      "AB8"      "EGFP1-10"

Note
The input as shown in the question:
sample.names1 <- c("S0938-CR1", "S0957-AB8", "S0971-EGFP1-10")


sample.names <- sub("^[^-]+-", "", sample.names1)

sample.names
[1] "CR1"      "AB8"      "EGFP1-10"

This finds text from the start of the string up to and including the first - and replaces it with an empty string.
